# Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ a root of $f(x)=x^3-3x-1$. Prove $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I encountered the following claim:

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ a root of $f(x)=x^3-3x-1$. Prove $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

The explanation included something of the form:

Since $f$ has degree $3$ then it must include either two polynomials of degree one, or one of degree one and one of degree two.

Say it is the latter: $f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x^2+ax+b)$.
Then if there is a root $m/n \in \mathbb{Q}$ it must be either $1$ or $-1$, which clearly cannot satisfy $f(x)=0$.

I cannot see how the conclusion of it being in $\{-1,1\}$ was obtained (it mentioned something about $m$ dividing $-1$ and $n$ dividing the leading $1$).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[The rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)  is used.

It says that if $p/q$ is a rational root of a polynomial in one variable with integer coefficients such that $p$ and $q$ are coprime, then $p$ divides the constant term and $q$ divides the leading coefficient.

Comment: Ah! Wasn't familiar with that... Thanks!

Comment: @Anon, you are welcome. It's immensely useful theorem in practice.